# Hide div on specific url with css or js

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

I'm trying to hide a `.sidebar-item` on a specific link. I am using Laravel & Bootstrap.

I can hide it with CSS like so:

```
.sidebar-item {
display: none;
```

}

But that hides it everywhere and I only want it hidden on a specific url.

How can I hide it with CSS/JS?

Comment: You won't be able to do this with only CSS since it  is not aware of where it is being used. The usual solution would be to serve a different CSS file for that specific URL or have some javascript code that hides these elements dynamically after the content has been loaded from the server.

Comment: Why not just avoid outputting the item entirely on that page. `@if(!Request::is('your/url')` in the Blade template.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can achieve this using CSS and JavaScript. A simple way would be to check the URL of the page:

With jQuery:

```
document.ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('/my/url')) {
    //Hide the element.
    jQuery('.sidebar-item').hide();
  }
});
```

Without jQuery:

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('/my/url')) {
    //Hide the element.
    document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-item')[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

Alternatively, you could add a custom class to the `body` tag for each page in Laravel. This will allow you to customize specific pages using CSS. I'm not a Laravel developer, but you can see two examples here: http://dev-notes.eu/2016/10/add-body-class-on-laravel-views/

(following is reproduced from the above blog post)

**First method:**

> Pass a relevant variable from the blade template:

```
{{-- /views/articles/index.blade.php --}}
...
@extends('layouts.master', ['body_class' => 'articles index'])
...
```

> Then in /views/layouts/master.blade.php:

```
<body
  @unless(empty($body_class))
    class="{{$body_class}}"
  @endunless
  >
```

**Second method:**

> In the child blade template:

```
@section('pageClass', 'js-home-page')
```

> In the master:

```
<body class="@yield('pageClass')">
```

Let's say you added the 'my-custom-page' class to the `body` tag of the page you want .sidebar-item to be hidden on. You can then modify your CSS to the following:

```
.my-custom-page .sidebar-item {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `.hide()`'s jQuery function apply an animation?

Comment: Maybe that's not what the OP wants to do. He can still trigger inline css's property `display:none` with js as well.

Comment: I believe it should be `if (window.location.href.indexOf('/my/url') >=0)`. `indexOf` returns `-1` when it doesn't find the string, so the if loop would still fire when it is just `if (window.location.href.indexOf('/my/url'))`.

Answer (score 2):

A partial solution for assigning CSS properties based on current page url might be using [CSS :target pseudo selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/t/target/).